# Group rows of a 2d array by column value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, grouping

I have multidimensional array;
I have to group all subarrays having same ID.
I tried with chunk but it is not working.

---

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => A11495
            [CID] => 000020
            [msgtype] => Periodic Report
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
        
            [ID] => A11495
            [CID] => 000020
            [msgtype] => Periodic Report
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => A11495
            [CID] => 000020
            [msgtype] => Periodic Report
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => A11496
            [CID] => 000020
            [msgtype] => Periodic Report
            
        )
    )
```

Expecting output as below array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => A11495
                    [CID] => 000020
                    [msgtype] => Periodic Report
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => A11495
                    [CID] => 000020
                    [msgtype] => Periodic Report
                    
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => A11495
                    [CID] => 000020
                    [msgtype] => Periodic Report
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (   
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => A11496
                    [CID] => 000020
                    [msgtype] => Periodic Report
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [ID] => A11496
                    [CID] => 000020
                    [msgtype] => Periodic Report
                    
                )
        )       
    )
```

Comment: use array unique http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Comment: You could use named arrays. Loop trough the array. for each array check if array[Id] exists. add the info to that array (array_push(array[id], info) If not create the array with the data

Answer (score 1):

Try something likes this:

```
<?php
    $oldArray = array();
    $newArray = array();

    foreach($oldArray as $item){
        if(isset($newArray[$item['ID']])){
            array_push($newArray[$item['ID']], $item);
        }else{
            $newArray[$item['ID']] = [];
            array_push($newArray[$item['ID']], $item);
        }
    }
?>
```